# Efficiently and simply convert from long-format to wide-format in pandas and/or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some very simple data that is provided in long format, and I would like to convert into an array. The row/col indices are strings (but could be non-sequential ints) and the values are floats. I have generated some simplified data below. Note that the true raw data needs to be cleaned before conversion to an array and hence the starting point is a pandas dataframe.

All solutions below yield the expected output, but none of the solutions tested seem very satisfactory. The pandas pivot/pivot_table solutions are elegant but orders of magnitude slower than the numpy solution that is much less readable.

Has anyone run into this issue before, and if so, have you found a clean and fast solution?

### Generate data

```
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import random
import scipy.sparse

In [2]:
pairs = list(itertools.product('ABCD', repeat=2))
random.shuffle(pairs)
data = [(x,y,v) for (x,y),v in list(zip(pairs, np.linspace(0,1,len(pairs))))]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['row','col','value'], index=range(1,len(data)+1))

In [6]:
df

Out[6]:
    row     col     value
1   D   A   0.000000
2   B   A   0.066667
3   D   B   0.133333
4   C   C   0.200000
5   A   A   0.266667
6   B   B   0.333333
7   C   B   0.400000
8   A   B   0.466667
9   A   C   0.533333
10  C   D   0.600000
11  D   C   0.666667
12  C   A   0.733333
13  A   D   0.800000
14  D   D   0.866667
15  B   D   0.933333
16  B   C   1.000000
```

### Expected output

```
array([[0.26666667, 0.46666667, 0.53333333, 0.8       ],
       [0.06666667, 0.33333333, 1.        , 0.93333333],
       [0.73333333, 0.4       , 0.2       , 0.6       ],
       [0.        , 0.13333333, 0.66666667, 0.86666667]])
```

### Solution 1: using pivot_table in pandas

```
In [16]:
%%timeit
pivoted_arr1 = df.pivot_table(index='row', columns='col', values='value').values

3.77 ms ± 159 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

### Solution 1b: using pivot in pandas

```
In [17]:
%%timeit
pivoted_arr1b = df.pivot(index='row', columns='col', values='value').values

1.15 ms ± 6.98 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

### Solution 2: using coo_matrix in scipy

```
In [11]:
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['row','col','value'], index=range(1,len(data)+1))

In [18]:
%%timeit
df_indexed = df.set_index(['row', 'col'])
pivoted_arr2 = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((df_indexed.value, (df_indexed.index.labels[0], df_indexed.index.labels[1]))).toarray()

1.3 ms ± 29.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

### Solution 3: using numpy

```
In [19]:
%%timeit
arr = df.values
rows, row_pos = np.unique(arr[:, 0], return_inverse=True)
cols, col_pos = np.unique(arr[:, 1], return_inverse=True)
pivoted_arr3 = np.zeros((len(rows), len(cols)))
pivoted_arr3[row_pos, col_pos] = arr[:, 2]

112 µs ± 487 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

So the reason for this is that Pandas has a lot of overhead. So it shouldn't be surprising that one complicated Pandas method is slower that a few cheap numpy equations when the input is small. You can't conclude any with such a small test.

So what happens if you test with a big example?

```
pairs = list(itertools.product('abcd', repeat=2))
random.shuffle(pairs)
data = [(x,y,v) for (x,y),v in list(zip(pairs, np.linspace(0,1,len(pairs))))]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['row','col','value'], index=range(1,len(data)+1))
```

**Pivot Small Test**

```
In [21]:
%%timeit
pivoted_arr1b = df.pivot(index='row', columns='col', values='value').values
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.27 ms per loop
```

**Numpy Small Test**

```
In [22]:
%%timeit
arr = df.values
rows, row_pos = np.unique(arr[:, 0], return_inverse=True)
cols, col_pos = np.unique(arr[:, 1], return_inverse=True)
pivoted_arr3 = np.zeros((len(rows), len(cols)))
pivoted_arr3[row_pos, col_pos] = arr[:, 2]
The slowest run took 4.68 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 120 µs per loop
```

**Make a Large Test**

```
In [26]:
pairs = list(itertools.product('qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM', repeat=2))
random.shuffle(pairs)
data = [(x,y,v) for (x,y),v in list(zip(pairs, np.linspace(0,1,len(pairs))))]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['row','col','value'], index=range(1,len(data)+1))
```

**Pivot Large Test**

```
In [27]:
%%timeit
pivoted_arr1b = df.pivot(index='row', columns='col', values='value').values
100 loops, best of 3: 2.03 ms per loop
```

**Pivot Large Test**

```
In [28]:
%%timeit
arr = df.values
rows, row_pos = np.unique(arr[:, 0], return_inverse=True)
cols, col_pos = np.unique(arr[:, 1], return_inverse=True)
pivoted_arr3 = np.zeros((len(rows), len(cols)))
pivoted_arr3[row_pos, col_pos] = arr[:, 2]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.27 ms per loop
```

So with a much large test case pandas is actually faster. Not only is it faster, but the time complexity is better too. When the number of rows was multiplied by 13, the time didn't even double.

If you want to apply this operation on a lot of small matrices none of this will help. But that's not what Pandas is really for.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. In this case, I have a large number of such smallish matrices to calculate. On the numpy side, do you know if there is a more elegant solution that maintains the speed for small matrices?